# regular-expression in java

Tags: java, regex, validation, passwords

I am using this regular expression in a java file to validate the password.

```
"^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[A-Z])\w*$"
```

It's showing the error :

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

Can anybody tell me what mistake I am doing in this?(I don't know anything about regular expressions. I copied it from google.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java string literals you need to escape the backslashes.

```
"^\\w*(?=\\w*\\d)(?=\\w*[a-z])(?=\\w*[A-Z])\\w*$"
```

You can also simplify your regular expression by removing the first `\\w*` as it is not needed.